# Setting DataContext using StaticResource

Tags: wpf, viewmodel, datacontext, resourcedictionary

I am trying to set the ViewModel as the DataContext of the View using the following XAML code:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:MyViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>

<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/MA_Resources/MA_ResourceDictionary.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <local:MyViewModel x:Key="myViewModel" x:Name="myVM" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

But, I observe that the view-model constructor is called twice. I understand the the view-model is  getting instantiated twice in XAML and that I should set the DataContext as the StaticResource from the Resources. However, I am not able to figure out how to set the DataContext with the StaticResource.
I tried the following but it's giving an exception:

```
<UserControl .... DataContext="{StaticResource myViewModel}" >
```

Please help me figuring out what should be the appropriate XAML code for assigning the DataContext.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to reference the static resource, if it is defined later in the xaml file. Therefore, you could do the following:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/MA_Resources/MA_ResourceDictionary.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <local:MyViewModel x:Key="myViewModel" x:Name="myVM" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="myViewModel"/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

I wonder why you want do define the ViewModel as a static resource. Personally, I would prefer the instantiation in the setter of the `DataContext`.

Comment: The problem is if you are binding a property to something that doesn't inherit datacontext (i.e. DataGridColumn's Visibility property), then it makes it a heck of a lot easier to do the binding with a source={StaticResource VM}.

Comment: For d:DataContext, use: d:UserControl.DataContext